# Cannot use a constant reference of experimental::optional when using clang & libstdc++

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, clang++, libstdc++

I'm taking a **constant reference of an experimental::optional<>** variable, but when I use **operator->()** on it, I have a compile error, but only when using **clang++ *and* libstdc++**.

```
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::experimental::optional<std::vector<int>> opt;
    const auto &rf = opt;

    opt.emplace();
    opt->push_back(1);

    std::cout << "opt->size() = " << opt->size()
              << " rf->size() = " << rf->size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program:

```
$ clang++ -W -Wall -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ test.cc && ./a.out
opt->size() = 1 rf->size() = 1  # OK

$ g++ -W -Wall -std=c++14 test.cc && ./a.out
opt->size() = 1 rf->size() = 1  # OK

$ clang++ -W -Wall -std=c++14 test.cc
In file included from test.cc:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/optional:576:16: error: call to '__constexpr_addressof' is ambiguous
      { return __constexpr_addressof(this->_M_get()); }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:14:40: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::operator->' requested here
              << " rf->size() = " << rf->size() << "\n";
                                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/optional:173:20: note: candidate function [with _Tp = const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, $1 = <>]
    constexpr _Tp* __constexpr_addressof(_Tp& __t)
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/experimental/optional:180:17: note: candidate function [with _Tp = const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, $1 = <>]
    inline _Tp* __constexpr_addressof(_Tp& __t)
                ^
1 error generated.
```

This error occurs whenever I use a constant reference: apparently non-constant references are OK.

I'm using Linux Mint 18 with these versions of g++/libstdc++ 5.4.0 and clang++ 3.8.0:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ dpkg-query -s libstdc++-5-dev
...
Version: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4
...

$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Is this a bug in my program, libstdc++, or clang++?

**Update**: The problem goes away with clang **3.9.0**.  (As explained below by Richard Smith and Ville Voutilainen, it seems that libstdc++ is expecting the compiler to behave in a certain way that doesn't match clang 3.8.0.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That certainly looks like a clang bug to me, because the overloads it diagnoses as ambiguous have mutually-exclusive enable_if constraints, so it shouldn't be possible that they are ambiguous.

Comment: The SFINAE conditions on `__constexpr_addressof` require that the compiler substitutes into packs that expand to zero elements. That behavior (and the relative order of expansion and substitution in general) is not specified by the standard.

Comment: Ah, kinky. The problem could certainly be avoided in libstdc++.

Comment: FWIW, I installed clang **3.9.0** and the problem went away, which is good enough for me. :)  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I will see if I can fix the problem in libstdc++, all the way back to gcc 5: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-12/msg00419.html

Comment: For historic reference, the behavior was changed in clang: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23840